# UIButton inside UIView not clickable

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm a little stuck on this one, I have a `UIButton` inside a `UIViewController`, but for some reason the `UIButton` is not responding.

```
_downloadButton = [[DownloadButtonViewController alloc] init];
_downloadButton.issue = _issue;
_downloadButton.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x, self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.height + 20, 200, 27);
[self.view addSubview:_downloadButton.view];

UIButton *tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
tmpButton.titleLabel.text = @"test";
tmpButton.frame = CGRectMake(_downloadButton.view.frame.origin.x, _downloadButton.view.frame.origin.y - 30, _downloadButton.view.frame.size.width, _downloadButton.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:tmpButton];
```

To see if nothing was overlapping it, I added another `UIButton` a little lower, even if I add it on the same position it still works.

The structure of my application is like this

```
- UIViewController
    - UIScrollView
        - ThumbCover
            - UIImageView
            - DownloadButton --> NOT WORKING
            - UIButton --> WORKING
            - UILabel
        - ThumbCover
            - UIImageView
            - DownloadButton --> NOT WORKING
            - UIButton --> WORKING
            - UILabel
        - ThumbCover
            - UIImageView
            - DownloadButton --> NOT WORKING
            - UIButton --> WORKING
            - UILabel
        - ThumbCover
            - UIImageView
            - DownloadButton --> NOT WORKING
            - UIButton --> WORKING
            - UILabel
```

The `DownloadButton` is just a simple `UIButton`, nothing special at all.

Comment: try changing the position of your uibutton and check

Comment: did not see the code to add action on the button.

Comment: are you overriding any of the touch methods of `DownloadButtonViewController`?

Comment: @Neo, it doesn't matter where I place it, the `DownloadButton` just never responds

Comment: @Veelian, without an action a button can still be visibly clickable, doesn't matter

Comment: @KDaker Nope, I'm not overriding anything, when I just add the `DownloadButtonViewController` to another view, it just works

Comment: ok mate just try bellow code i just change two lines just see my code...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have specified the height of the viewcontroller's view as 27

```
_downloadButton.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x, self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.height + 20, 200, 27);
```

If your button's frame is outside the frame of its parent view (viewcontroller's view), the abovesaid frame, it wouldn't respond to your touches

Comment: Thanks, good advice, but it seems this is not the case, I can add the `DownloadButtonViewController` to anywhere else and it would just work, in fact I have another `UIScrollView` with the same button inside and there it just works

Comment: Finally figured it out, it had something to do with the size of the frame in IB, not sure why it wasn't set by `_downloadButton.view.frame`

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually set some target for the button? (Asking since in the provided code, I cannot see that!) Otherwise, it would not response at all of course.

Comment: As stated before, the button is not visually clickable, `tmpButton` has no target too, but you can still see if it's clickable or not.

Answer (score 0):

i put your code but change two line which overrite so just try this code...

```
_downloadButton = [[DownloadButtonViewController alloc] init];
_downloadButton.issue = _issue;
_downloadButton.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x, self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.height + 20, 200, 27);

UIButton *tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
tmpButton.titleLabel.text = @"test";
tmpButton.frame = CGRectMake(_downloadButton.view.frame.origin.x, _downloadButton.view.frame.origin.y - 30, _downloadButton.view.frame.size.width, _downloadButton.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:tmpButton];
[self.view addSubview:_downloadButton.view];
```

hope this help you...

:)

Comment: What are the exact changes you've made?

Comment: i just override button see the line [self.view addSubview:_downloadButton.view]; possition is last just put last line at last of code.. :)

Comment: I doubt that makes a difference, tmpButton was just an example to show that interaction in the view was actually working, besides, the button is already added at the very end in my view

Comment: It's not clickable, yes, i have a target set up, it's only not clickable in this case, in any other cases it works.

Comment: ok and for this reason i just override you tmpbutton with _downloadbutton. ok now just put this line at the end of above all code     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_downloadButton.view]; just try may this work dude.. :)

Comment: I tried that before, it doesn't work. For some reason the button inside the `DownloadButtonViewController` is not responding in this case. I can add the exact same code anywhere else and it would work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16807/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-woutr-be)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems like my animated transitioning is not yet completed. I forgot to to put `completeTransition:Bool` at the end of my  `animateTransition:context` method making all the buttons inside my view controller disabled and not `userinteractionEnabled`.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at you this code

```
_downloadButton = [[DownloadButtonViewController alloc] init];
```

Not that i mean your naming way is wrong but I doubt if your DownloadButtonViewController is UIButton or not. Just to make sure open your **DownloadButtonViewController.h** and check if you have got this or not

```
@interface DownloadButtonViewController : UIButton
```

Comment: `DownloadButtonViewController` is not a UIButton, it's a UIView with a `UIButton` inside

Answer (score -3):

```
replace this line.. 

tmpButton.titleLabel.text = @"test";
```

as

```
[tmpButton setTitle: @"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```