# Adding a uiview that contions some uibuttons not works correctly iphone monotouch

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I'm using this codes to add 3 `UIButtons` in a `UIView` and then add them to my screen.

```
UIView  buttonsContainerView = new UIView (new Rectangle (0,0,(int) this.View .Frame .Width ,40));
            UIButton  b;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                b= new RltTabBarButton ();
                b.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets (5,5,5,100);
                if(i==0){
                    b.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/Placeholder.png"),
                                          UIControlState.Normal );
                    b.TitleLabel .Text = "Details";
                    b.Frame = new RectangleF (0,350,108,40);
                    b.Enabled =true ;
                }else if(i==1){
                    b.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/Placeholder.png"),
                                          UIControlState.Normal );
                    b.TitleLabel .Text = "Map";
                    b.Frame = new RectangleF (110,350,100,40);
                    b.Enabled =true ;
                }else if(i==2){


                    b.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/Placeholder.png"),
                                          UIControlState.Normal );
                    b.TitleLabel .Text = "Agent";
                    b.Frame = new RectangleF (212,350,108,40);
                    b.Enabled =true ;
                }
                buttonsContainerView .AddSubview (b);

            }
this.View .AddSubview (buttonsContainerView );
```

When I run my application. Buttons added in their correct place. but they do not include any `Text` on their `TitleLable`. While I set this Item. Also they look like some images so that i can not click on them and interact with them.

I set their `Enabled` field `true` but not any changes.

EDIT: 
According to answers I changed my code to this:

```
UIView  buttonsContainerView = new UIView (new Rectangle (0,0,(int) this.View .Frame .Width ,40));

            UIButton  DetailsButton= new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect  );
            DetailsButton.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets (5,5,5,100);
            DetailsButton.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/Placeholder.png"),
                                  UIControlState.Normal );
            DetailsButton.SetTitle ("Details",UIControlState.Normal );
            DetailsButton.Frame = new RectangleF (0,350,108,40);
            buttonsContainerView .AddSubview (DetailsButton);

            UIButton  MapButton= new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect );
            MapButton.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets (5,5,5,100);
            MapButton.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/Placeholder.png"),
                                          UIControlState.Normal );
            MapButton.SetTitle ("Map",UIControlState.Normal );
            MapButton.Frame = new RectangleF (110,350,100,40);
            buttonsContainerView .AddSubview (MapButton);

            UIButton  AgentButton= new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect  );
            AgentButton.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/Placeholder.png"),
                                          UIControlState.Normal );
            AgentButton.SetTitle ("Agent",UIControlState.Normal );
            AgentButton.Frame = new RectangleF (212,350,108,40);
            buttonsContainerView .AddSubview (AgentButton);

            this.View .AddSubview (buttonsContainerView );
```

But not any changes. we do not able to click on buttons. Their look like images. I believe that it is related to `buttonsContainerView` and maybe its `EnableInputClicksWhenVisible`. When I debug the app this view, debugger have some exeption when wants to execute its value.
I was able to copy just head of this:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UIView enableInputClicksWh…
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
The problem is that I set the hieght of `buttonsContainerView`( The view that contains buttons
) 40. but is set the Height position of buttons 350. 
When button's frame is outside the frame of its parent view it wouldn't respond to your touches.

For more info: [UIButton inside UIView not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470188/uibutton-inside-uiview-not-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment, but I cannot comment yet. I find your implementation odd and I tend to think it would cause ARC to misbehave (I assume ARC since you do not have any release code). Why not just create 3 UIButtons instead of this loop and then add all of those to your UIView?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a new on monotouch and iphone. I don't know what is ARC. I implement them before this in separate buttons. In this way, they can click but also their text not appear. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SetTitle(); function of the UIButton in order to make it work. Otherwise, the TitleLabel won't be set.

```
button.SetTitle("MyTitle",UIControlState.Normal);
```

Comment: I wanna that this text be present in all states. By using this command the title is present in just one state. before this i used TitleLable.Text for showing title in all states.

Comment: Also Now in SetTitle command when I use 'Normal State' the text appear when i click on the button. I do not expect this.

Comment: If you don't set title for other state, it'll keep this one. If you don't want the text when you click on it you need to set a title for another state  SetTitle("", UIControlState.Highlighted)